# how do I supply 3.3V from my 5V arduino pro mini?

Tags: arduino, power-supply

I have a 5V Arduino Pro Mini that I want to connect with this 3.3V nRF24L01+ module. (On the other end I have the same nRF24L01+ module connected to an Arduino Uno which has a 3.3V pin that I know is safe to use.)

The nRF24L01+ modules I have are [these](http://arduino-direct.com/sunshop/index.php?l=product_detail&p=188).

The Arduino board this question relates to is [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11113).

Comment: The short solution is to power the RF module with two AA batteries. Long term, I'm going for 3.3V Arduinos instead of 5V.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a 3.3V voltage regulator. See DigiKey parts [here](http://www.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?FV=fff40027%2Cfff80182%2Cc00016&vendor=0&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ptm=0&fid=0&quantity=0&PV129=95&PV129=947&PV129=115&PV129=934&PV129=90&PV129=930&PV129=895&PV129=925&PV129=77&PV129=891&PV129=902&PV129=1049&PV129=75&PV129=885&PV129=899&PV129=533&PV129=61&PV129=892&PV129=896&PV129=911&PV129=459&PV129=25&PV129=884&PV129=83&PV129=894&PV129=914&PV129=253&PV129=1131&PV129=76&PV129=886&PV129=900&PV129=280&PV129=27&PV129=916&PV129=863&PV129=67&PV129=889&PV129=60&PV129=890&PV129=901&PV129=97&PV129=922&PV129=170&PV129=924&PV129=127&PV129=951&PV129=972&PV129=143&PV129=926&PV129=927&PV129=313&PV129=6&PV129=893&PV129=913&PV129=147&PV129=160&PV129=104&PV129=233&PV129=1&PV129=866&PV129=865&PV129=7&PV129=887&PV129=13&PV129=919&PV129=898&PV129=244&PV129=15&PV129=17&PV129=1054&PV129=279&PV129=1056&stock=1). It looks like all of them accept a 5V input and I set a 20mA output minimum (the max supply consumption of your module is 13.5mA)

Comment: Thanks, this I see as a proper solution. In the end I opted for 3.3V Arduinos instead.

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't just add a resistor to bring down the voltage?

Comment: @DominicM You can't just add a resistor to bring down the voltage because the current consumption is not constant - it goes from almost 0 (in which case the voltage drop over the resistor would be 0 as V=IR). A red LED  plus a ballast resistor to ensure 1mA minimum current might work, as the LEDs are typically specified as 1.8V drop and 20mA current.

Answer (score 2):

I've supplied my 3.3V GPS module from a 5V ATMega328 by using two 1N4001 diodes in series. It was not an optimal solution at 3.0V, but it was cheap and I had the diodes laying around.

The same solution may possibly work as a temporary hack if you need something immediately and don't want to wait on an order from a supplier.

Comment: At 10 to 20ma max, the drop should be ~0.72v on each, so it should give 3.5~3.6v. Which is perfect for OP.

Comment: Nice quick solution. I opted for 2 AA batteries though.